# url not working in MVC with parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a project in `MVC` and it has been working all right, but I have not been able to solve an error, I try to access a url that creates from `global. asax` with parameters but it gives me error code 404.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Unit",
        "Home/Unit/{id}/{name}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Unit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

here I create the route in jquery, I add the route to a div with text

```
 $('#nombreUnidad').append("<a href='Unit/" + param.Unidad.Id + "/" + param.Unidad.NombreUnidad + "'>Nombre: " + param.Unidad.NombreUnidad + "</a>");
```

so is my actionresult from my controller

```
public ActionResult Unit(int id, string name)
{

    return View("~/Views/Home/Unit.cshtml");
}
```

I want to get to that view by clicking on a div, yes, in this case the view will have a model, it is something like profiles, that is why in jquery I create the path over the text of a div to be able to return the view with the data of the unit that I chose

Comment: have you checked the url in inspect element?

Comment: sorry, but how can I do that?

Comment: actually after clicking on the link you can check the url. and paste it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this in the div click event.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST", //Post or Get
                url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ id:1, name: 'pp' }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                        //code to handle the response
                },
                error: function () {
                    //code to handle error
                }
            });
```

Comment: this needs to go directly in your razor page btw. not in a js page. If you want it in a js page you can use `var myUrl = "@Url.Action("Action","Controller")"` in your razor page. Then `url = myUrl` in the above code

Comment: I want to do it directly from razor, the div already has in its url the parameters, so that the actionresult recives them and returns me a view with the data

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner way to approach this. You can use your jquery like this:

```
 $('#nombreUnidad').append(function(){
        return $("<a>").attr("href", $(this).attr("data-appUrl") + ...).text("link text");
 });
```

This code gets your URL directly from a data-appUrl attribute in your HTML. It is much easier to pass a URL directly into razor. Something like this:

```
<div id="nombreUnidad" data-appUrl="@Url.Content("~/Home/Unit/")">
  <span>Here is some <b>sample text</b></span>
</div>
```

The code `data-appUrl="@Url.Content("~/Home/Unit/")"` helps you make sure that the exact URL is being used for the current page.

Here is a sample usage of the jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/61226/